# How to use transform_reduce to fill up an iterator with results? c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to fill the result iterator with the results of foo(n).  So from 0 to n, each times2(n), so for foo(5) the result iterator should represent {0,2,4,6,8,10}.  Not allowed to use vectors or for loops. I'm stuck with the documentation of transform/transform reduce, not sure what's going wrong. Thanks in advance.  Also how to get current itr position in the lambda function, within transform, I would like to store in a Pair.

```
uint64_t times2(uint64_t n) {
    return 2 * n;
}

counting_iterator<uint64_t> foo(uint64_t bound) {
   counting_iterator<uint64_t> start(0);
   counting_iterator<uint64_t> finish(bound);
   counting_iterator<uint64_t> result(0);
   transform_reduce(
        start,finish,result,[](const uint64_t n){

           return times2(n);}
    );
   return result;
}
```

Comment: That seems like just `transform`. Any particular reason you're using `transform_reduce`?

Comment: Also, you *cannot have* the current iterator position. If you want that, don't use these algorithm functions, write your own instead.

Comment: "Also how to get current itr position in the lambda function" doesn't `n` represent that in this case?

Comment: `boost::counting_iterator<uint64_t>` can't possibly produce a sequence `{0,2,4,6,8,10}`. Having `foo` return `counting_iterator` makes no sense. Since you are apparently using Boost, you might want to look at [`transform_iterator`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/transform_iterator.html)

Comment: Are you trying to create what a python person would call a generator? An iterator should have a container to iterate, but a generator should not.  If you want to fill some new container with the numbers, you can do that with counting_iterator and back_inserter. You cannot produce a sequence using any variation of reduce -- the sole purpose of reduce is to get rid of the sequence and reduce it to a single value (for example, a sum).

Comment: I was thinking to use transform reduce to both create the result collection and then reduce it to only a maximum value.